# Why are JMS messages acknowledged automatically

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

Why are JMS messages acknowledged after `onMessage()` listener method returns even if acknowledgment mode is set to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`?

If you look at the `commitIfNecessary` method in the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` class, you can see the following:

```
protected void commitIfNecessary(Session session, Message message) throws JMSException {
    // Commit session or acknowledge message.
    if (session.getTransacted()) {
        // Commit necessary - but avoid commit call within a JTA transaction.
        if (isSessionLocallyTransacted(session)) {
            // Transacted session created by this container -> commit.
            JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(session);
        }
    } else if (message != null && isClientAcknowledge(session)) {
        message.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

After debugging, I confirm that `message.acknowledge()` is called.

I thought that `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` means I need to acknowledge message manually?

Any idea?

Thanks, Mickael

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the message listener container is the client, not your listener.

If you wish to manually ack (perhaps after receiving a number of messages), don't use a listener container; you can use a `JmsTemplate.execute()` with a `SessionCallback` and create your own consumer.

Comment: Interesting, so if I want to use the asynchronous model with listener, the only option is to throw an exception inside the onMessage method so that the message is not acknowledged?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; client ack is intended to defer acknowledgement but they eventually have to be acked; messages remain in an 'unacked' state until acknowledged; they will be requeued if the connection is lost. Throwing an exception will cause the message to be either dropped or requeued, depending on whether you are using transactions, the ack mode, and/or which container type you are using. With a SimpleMessageListenerContainer and AUTO, the message will be requeued; with a DefaultMessageListenerContainer and AUTO, the message will be dropped, unless the session is transacted.

Comment: I thought that CLIENT_ACK means it is the responsability of the consumer to acknowledge the message after successful processing. If the consumer doesn't ack the message inside the onMessage method, the message will not be ack and therefore requeued.

Comment: It will only be requeued when the session is closed; the broker doesn't know when you are finished or whether you are using batched acks; see [Message.acknowledge()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#acknowledge()).